# How do I get the .deb for Rhythmbox 0.13.2 to install on Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: 9.10, rhythmbox

I'm wanting to get some of the new features in Rhythmbox 0.13.2 on my aging Ubuntu laptop w/out having to upgrade to the latest version of Ubuntu.  I'm currently at 9.10.

One option for installing the new version of Rhythmbox is to uninstall the package I have then install the tarball in `/usr/local` and then figure out which dependencies I need to install.  I'd rather use the package management system to manage the dependencies.

This may be an elementary question, but is installing the tarball and looking for the dependencies my only option here?  Or can I somehow get the `.deb` from a repository and install that instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this method you are looking to use would cause you more headache than anything else. The dependencies are going to be many, and the more you add, the more you have to upgrade other things. Eventually you will be better off upgrading your system.

Installing from the deb is safer, but it could also cause breakage even if you use the `--force-all` option to install. My humble suggestion is that you upgrade (yes I know you don't want to, but if you want the latest, you'll have to do that).